# How is this base conversion property explained?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

converting $(7)_9$ to base 3 = 21, converting $(77)_9$ to base 3 = 2121 and so on. I am curious as to what exactly makes this true. I am guessing it has something to do with the relation of powers as hexadecimals can be converted to base 2 in a similar fashion but would appreciate a solid explanation

Answer (score 1):

Each base 9 digit converts independently (as long as you pad with zeroes) to two base three digits.

Answer (score 0):

Expand $ (77)_9$ $ = 7*3^2 + 7*1$.  Now $(7)_9 = (21)_3 = 2*3+1$.  Replacing that in our original expansion yields $$(77)_9 = (2*3+1)*3^2 + (2*3+1)*1.$$  Now use the distributive law to see that 
$$(77)_9 = 2*3^3 + 1*3^2 + 2*3+1 = (2121)_3.$$

Similarly, each hexadecimal digit can be replaced by the corresponding bit string to convert to base 2.